# Why go to definition for int redirect me to an empty file on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

When I go to definition for type `int` in Visual Studio I should be redirected to `Int32` class from metadata. Instead I am redirected to an empty file. What could be the problem?

I am using c# and visual studio 2022.